# ng2-pdfjs-viewer for extracting text

Tags: ng2-pdfjs-viewer

Is there any possibility of using ng2-pdfjs-viewer for extracting solely the text of a pdf file, e.g. as a string? I want to extract text and regex it for cutting out certain paragraphs depending on the text inside of them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ng2-pdfjs-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdfjs-viewer)
is an angular wrapper over pdfjs and viewerjs. The capabilities of pdfjs is exposed using an attribute `PDFViewerApplication` and `PDFViewerApplicationOptions`. If extracting text is feasible using pdfjs, these attributes can be used to call internal functions whic does that.

PS: I authored ng2-pdfjs-viewer

Comment: can we add few extra functions inside viewer.js using your library?

Comment: @user3660375 Yes - you can